# Необычное использование оператора delete[]

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

Что означает данная конструкция. Почему разрешается использовать в квадратных скобках значение.

```
char* p = new char[1];
delete[2] p;
```

Comment: VC++ говорит - "нестандартное расширение. Значение вычисляется, но игнорируется"...

Comment: У меня это вообще вызывает ошибку... С какими флагами вы компилировали, что у вас это пропустило? Я пробовал g++ и clang++ - выбивает ошибку

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch На вижуал студио компилируется вообще без флагов: https://godbolt.org/g/8LHgFK

Comment: @HolyBlackCat в майкрософте опять решили, что стандарт не их путь...

Comment: А что бы это значило? По коду? Что будет удалено при такой конструкции? Что то типа realloc с размером 2?

Comment: @NewView *"Значение вычисляется, но игнорируется (c) Harry"* Я так понимаю, речь про содержимое скобок.